# Xamarin Android Bluetooth scanning for devices does not find specific device

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I succesfully implemented the Code described [here](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2018/12/16/how-to-detect-nearby-bluetooth-devices-with-net-and-xamarin-android/).
I do find my phone (Samsung Galaxy A51) or my portable radio transceiver (Bluetooth 4.1)
But somehow I can't seem to find my optical read-out head (Bluetooth 2.1). Is it because of the Bluetooth version? How do I fix this?

Comment: Could it be that your optical read-out head is already paired with your phone? I can observe the same with my bluetooth headset. Once paired it does not show up for other devices anymore

Comment: Oh my god of course... why didnt I think of this... Thank you Michael it's working now...